# Install 16.04 AMD R7 Graphics issues

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation, graphics

I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 or 17.10 (same issue for both) as a dual boot along side my windows OS.

Graphics:
Display Adapters
    AMD Radeon(TM) R7 Graphics (Device ID = 9874)

Processor
    AMD A10 Extreme Edition Radeon R8, 4C +8G

1. Create New Partition to Install ubuntu as dual boot.
2. Create bootable usb and try to install ubuntu 16.04 or 17.10 (tried both)
3. On install get stuck at the splash screen.
4. Try again and highlight "try ubuntu" press "e" and edit boot to include "nomodeset" flag.
5. Able to load ubuntu and install the OS while in the "try now" version.
6. Once installed I get the same issue with the splash screen hanging.
7. Repeat step 4 and load OS.
8. Once in the OS I try to install the AMD driver for ubuntu.
   http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx
9. When its installed I try log back in and hit a logon loop.

I have tried everything, I am pulling my hair out, all I want is a separate Linux partition and AMD wont let me :-(
I have searched the internet and this forum. I'm not an expert in Linux so go easy on me.

Im very confused about the the AMD driver I should download and try and install, maybe I got the wrong one and this is why I got the logon loop.

Either way, I have deleted the partition and will try again, any advice would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but in case someone else needs, removing amdgpu-pro solves this. Here is how to:

- at login screen, press ctrl+alt+F3 to open terminal
- use your login credentials to login(you need to write your username first)
- type `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`
- wait for the process to finish, then `sudo reboot`